# Redips - how to get object before event.deleted handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, redips.drag

This is my code:

```
   REDIPS.drag.event.deleted = function(){
    //TODO
   }
```

This is fired when an object is dropped in the 'trash' cell. I am trying to get the object id before it gets deleted, because I alse want to delete it in the database. How can I do this?

In the redips documentation it says :

> deleted(cloned) Event handler invoked if element is deleted (dropped
>   to the "trash" table cell). Parameters: {Boolean} cloned Optional True
>   if cloned element is directly moved to the trash (in one move). If
>   cloned element is dropped to the table and then moved to the trash
>   then "cloned" parameter will be set to false.
>
> src:http://www.redips.net/javascript/redips-drag-documentation/#event:deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the clicked function, you can set a backup for the div that will be deleted.

```
        rd.event.clicked=function(currentCell){
            classDetailPage.lastGridItemId = $(currentCell).find("div")[0].id;
        };
        rd.event.deleted = function(){
            classDetailPage.deleteGridItem(classDetailPage.lastGridItemId);     
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside most of REDIPS.drag event handlers it's possible to retrieve reference to the dragged DIV element with **rd.obj** (or REDIPS.drag.obj). Here is how:

```
rd.event.clicked = function(currentCell) {
    classDetailPage.lastGridItemId = rd.obj.id;
};
rd.event.deleted = function() {
    classDetailPage.deleteGridItem(classDetailPage.lastGridItemId);     
};
```

... or simply use reference to DIV element directly in "deleted" event handler:

```
rd.event.deleted = function() {
    classDetailPage.deleteGridItem(rd.obj.id);
};
```